# Removing items from custom list adapter 

Tags: android, listview

**Problem** i have custom list adapter view with checkboxes i want to remove list items on checked items basis.this is my code

```
                  for(int i=0;i<adapter.getCount();i++)
                    {   
                        System.out.println("Adapter Count:"+adapter.getCount());
                        if(checks.get(i)==true)
                        {
                            checks.put(i,false);
                            adapter.remove(feedbackList.get(i));                
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();                                                 
                        }

                    }
```

its almost working fine and items are removing but some items wont get remove even checked...if any one could help me...
Thanks in advance

Comment: @Vivek this is my code if you can just have a look on that

Comment: Just so you know, instead of `if(checks.get(i)==true)`, you can just use `if(checks.get(i))`.

Comment: So does the item stay checked and in the adapter? Or does the item uncheck itself but doesn't remove?

Comment: is adapter is Adapter of feedbackList ?

Comment: @Austin no if items doesn't get remove it got uncheck!!

Comment: @DheereshSingh yes adaoter is of FeedbackList(List)

Comment: Alright then `feedbackList.get(i)`, and `checks.get(i)` are not referring to the same ListItem it seems. Is the app removing things items that aren't checked?

Comment: @Austin should i try ListView.invalidateViews();

Comment: @Austin look at the sprigg answer the guy seems to be right

Answer (score 1):

You are modifing your adapter, while you are iterating over it. You should find a better way to do that.

Example:

You have 3 elements in your adapter and want to remove all(`1`,`2`,`3`).

After removing `1` your adapter has only (`2`,`3`) left.

Your counter `i` is on the second field of your adapter
So you remove `3` and your 'for' is finished.

`2` will not be removed.

**EDIT** (an solution): 
i didn't verify it, but this should work:

```
LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();
for(int i=0;i<adapter.getCount();i++)
{   
     System.out.println("Adapter Count:"+adapter.getCount());
     if(checks.get(i)==true)
     {
         list.addFirst(i);                                           
     }
}  
//list will now contain all positions of checked items (e.g. 1,5,7,8,9,..)
for(int i=0;i<list.length;i++)
{
   //list.get(i) gets the index of the checked item   
   adapter.remove(feedbackList.get(list.get(i)));             
   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();           
}
```

Comment: yes you are right if item at **1** got removed the item at position **2** now will be at position **1** and it will never got removed...

Comment: there are several ways. for example copy your data to a temp list, iterate over that list and remove the items in your adapter. or first get all positions of items to remove and after that remove the items from last to first position. By going from last to first you will avoid the moving of items to remove

Comment: isn't it is possible by some simple way...??

Comment: look at my edited answer. something like this should work (maybe you need some minor changes (e.g. convert Integer to int) to make it work)

Comment: FeedBackList is a data structure(List<Order>)...and it contains objects not linked list

Comment: if we remove an item from array list what would actually happens with the rest of the elements...i mean did there indexes get change to fill the empty spaces??

Comment: is there any way i could just spare from the shifting of the indexes??

Comment: you could do so, but modifiing an list or something like that while iterating over it is not very nice (in my opinion). It is ok, that Feedbacklist contains Objects. I just keep the indexes of checked items in this linkedlist and use this list to get the objects of feedbacklist.

removing an item from an arraylist lets all items "behind" this item move forward.

Comment: i don't understand why you are making linked list when there is already checks sparseBooleanArray that contains checks state??

Comment: i guess its a bad programming pratice

Comment: yeah you are right. sorry, but codiny with just a breadcrumb of code isn't that easy for me, so i just tried to make an easy solution i could figure out without all of your code. did i get this right?: 
checks is an array (same size as your adapteritems)
feedbackList is a list containing all your objects (no matter what these objects are)

If yes, than the solution is very easy: why iterating over adapter.getCount() and not checks.size()?

Comment: unfortunately i have to go to work now, and will not be able to answer you anymore in the next couple of hours :(
I think you need to figure out a solution by yourself, or anyone else may guide you

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adptr= new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),R.layout.custom_spinner_text,list)
String delete =adptr.getItem(0));
adptr.remove(delete);
```

Answer (score 0):

remove array item from the position and reload list by notifyDataSetChanged, method:

```
for(int i=0;i<adapter.getCount();i++)
                    {   
                        System.out.println("Adapter Count:"+adapter.getCount());
                        if(checks.get(i)==true)
                        {
                            checks.put(i,false);
                            //remove items from soruce                
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();                                                 
                        }

                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
 for(int i=0;i<feedbackList.size();i++)
        {
            if(checks.get(i) == true)
            {
                feedbackList.remove(i);
                checks.remove(i);
                i--;
            }
        }


adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

and use feedbackList and checks as a Class level variables

Comment: isnt that same to remove from adapter or from feedbackList

Comment: when you call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() then adapter change with new data set. So after changing the feedbackList, you are calling notifyDataSetChanged. It means adapter also changed. So I suggest first test code

Comment: if i remove any item from ArrayList data structure what will actually happens??does the rest of items move back to fill the position...also my checks is a SparseBooleanArray

Comment: feedbackList is of type Object i.e Feedback class

Comment: if feedbackList is a Object of Feedback class then why use need to use extra SparseBooleanArray to maintain checked items list. Use one more boolean attribute in feedback class and use setter and getter to set value to chceked items.

Comment: One more thing, use ArrayList instead of SparseBooleanArray and use my code. I hope your problem will resolve.

Comment: no feedbackList is a List<Feedback> feedbackList=new List<Feedback>();

Comment: and whats the problem in using sparseArray??

Comment: sparseArray I guess use hash-key pair to maintain list(I am not confirm), so this may create problem.  feedbackList is List is fine, but how you able to do new List<Feedback>(). Because you can not create the object of List like this. And I think changing sparse array into ArrayList is easy in your code. So first change this and try code.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to update your observers

```
for(DataSetObserver observer : observers) {
        observer.onChanged();
    }
```