# Remove items from beginning of ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I have a small app which loads images, puts them in a ListView. I would like to have a limit of items in the ListView, when new image is added at the end, an image is removed in beginning. My current implementation, although works, does not remove items nicely.
Here is my current code:

```
if (adapter.getCount() > 20) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        adapter.remove(adapter.getItem(0));
    }
}
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

The problem is that the position remain the same, but all images shift, meaning several images are skipped.

Comment: How about using the same logic that is used in queues (you're actually trying to follow the FIFO principle here that is employed in queues). You could just make use of a marker that keeps track of at the index at which the last image was added in the list When it reaches the size, you reset it and start from 0.

I'm still not entirely sure of your question. Correct me if I'm wrong

Answer (score 0):

This answer seems to explain what is likely causing your problem:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11027830/3570280

One of these two solutions might solve your problem:

If the images seem to be keeping their previous position, try putting **i** in for 0:

```
if (adapter.getCount() > 20) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        adapter.remove(adapter.getItem(i));
    }
}
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

This may help you keep up with the changes in position.

"Refreshing" the adapter and its surroundings every time you delete may reset the images' positions:

```
if (adapter.getCount() > 20) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        adapter.remove(adapter.getItem(0));
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

I recommend trying both and making minor adjustments to the code block to make it work. Maybe even try both of the solutions together.